# Pyinstaller doesn't find hidden import configargparse

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I am trying to compile a python program which imports configargparse, but pyinstaller doesn't find it, even if I specify it with hidden imports. I use following command: `pyinstaller.exe --onefile  --hidden-import=configargparse some_folder\viewer.py --log-level=DEBUG --debug=imports` but when running the exe I get:

```
# configargparse not found in PYZ
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "some_folder\viewer.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'configargparse'
[5976] Failed to execute script 'viewer' due to unhandled exception!
```

Especially weird is that I get this debug message when compiling:
`2711 DEBUG: Hidden import 'configargparse' already found`
which obviously when running it doesn't seem to be the case
I tried with a small sample program:

```
import configargparse
print(configargparse)
```

but that doesn't work either, same error as for my more complex program.
I could once compile this program, but I'm not sure anymore how and the obvious way doesn't seem to work. What am I missing?

Comment: can you install configargparse seperately?

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: create a [example]

Comment: @Alexander I did, please read the post. I did 20min, before you posted your comment. Take the file you see above and call the command I posted above

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'configargparse' has no attribute '__version__'`

Comment: Yes, sorry the `__version__` for some odd reason doesn't exist in the configargparse, but getting this error you already succeeded in importing the module, so I don't know why you didn't have to do this, what is your pysintaller version? Are you using windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

So I had to add my venv/lib/site-packages as an absolute path to pathex in the spec file.

Comment: I didn't... it worked fine for me right off the bat